# Matching to multiple items in a python data set

Tags: python

This code has been working fine for me:

```
a = '31'
b = ''
c = ''
d = ''

codes = [a, b, c, d]

set_one = ('07', '10', '17', '31')
set_two = ('01','02','03','04','05','06','08')
if any(s in test for test in codes for s in set_one):
  result = '"ONE"'
elif any(s in test for test in codes for s in set_two):
  result = '"TWO"'
else:
  result = 'NULL'

print(result)
```

In this example, `result` would print back `"ONE"`

If either a, b, c, or d is set to `01`, then result would print back `"TWO"`, etc etc.

This solution worked for a while as there was only ever one group of codes that could be represented in the equation, but I now need to account for both ONE and TWO being represented, (e.g. A = 07, B = 01).  If this were to happen, the "07" would be picked up by the first `if any` statement, and would report out `"ONE"`.

I need to build in the functionality so that if in the entire `codes` object, both groups are represented, (e.g. `codes = ['07','01','','']`), then it reports back `"THREE"`.

I'm not sure how to do that though as python is not my forte...

## edit

This works.  Thank you guys!

```
a = '01'
b = ''
c = ''
d = ''

codes = [a, b, c, d]

one_match = 0
two_match = 0

set_one = ('07', '10', '17', '31', 'CO', '12', '13', '25', '55', 'ZN', 'Z3', 'Z2')
set_two = ('01','02','03','04','05','06','08','11','14','15','16','18','19','20')
if any(s in test for test in codes for s in set_one):
  one_match = 1
if any(s in test for test in codes for s in set_two):
  two_match = 1

if one_match == 1 and two_match == 1:
    result = "MIX"
elif one_match == 1:
    result = "ONE ONLY"
elif two_match == 1:
    result = "TWO ONLY"
else:
    result = 'NULL'


print(result)
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: This would probably be more efficient if you used sets and set intersection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

test without `elif` and use an integer to count.

```
matches = 0
if any(s in test for test in codes for s in set_one):
  matches += 1
if any(s in test for test in codes for s in set_two):
  matches += 2
```

then use a list & `matches` as the index:

```
result = ["NULL","ONE","TWO","THREE"][matches]
```

Comment: I like it - nice!  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your code like this:

```
  result = 'NULL'

  if any(s in test for test in codes for s in set_one):
  result = '"ONE"'

  if any(s in test for test in codes for s in set_two):
  result = '"TWO"'

  print(result)
```

Probably this is not best practice, but i believe it works correctly.